# Boot on Intel MacBook Pro fails with IRQ index 0 not found

Tags: dual-boot, mac, macbook-pro

Using [these instructions](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/), I set up my 2019 Intel MacBook Pro to boot Ubuntu: partitioned the drive, installed [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), disabled secure boot, put Ubuntu 22.04 on a USB drive.

When it boots from the drive, it throws up a selector (Try or Install Ubuntu, OEM Install, EFI Options, etc.). I choose "Try or Install Ubuntu," and it shows a little bit of text (some `apple-properties` dumped), then ends with:

```
Integrity: Reading UEFI Secure Boot Certs is not supported on T2 Macs.
intel-lpss INT34BA:00: error -EINVAL: IRQ index 0 not found
```

I can't find anything online that's helpful.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to use?

Comment: 22.04. I found the [T2-Ubuntu](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu) repo and that was able to install a bootable system.